# knexjs return relations columns after insert and on select queries

Tags: typescript, knex.js

Hello I have doubts on the knex when doing the following,
I have an employee and department table where there is a 1: n relationship (an employee for many departments)
and I also have a relationship where an employee is the manager of a department:
And then I wanted to do the following with knex, when using a query to obtain a department, also return all the information from the manager of that department:

this is my relations:
[image]

this is my function to get Departament by name here i need get my manager with manager_id:

```
  public findByName = async (
    departament_name: string,
  ): Promise<Departament | undefined> => {
    const rawDepartament = await this.db
      .select('*')
      .from<Departament>(this.tableName)
      .where({ departament_name })
      .first();
    if (!rawDepartament) return undefined;
    return rawDepartament ;
  };
```

and also when doing a department insertion query I wanted to return the manager's data:

```
  public create = async (item: any): Promise<Departament> => {
    const trx = await this.transactionProvider();
    try {
      const rawExists = await this.findByName(item.departament_name);
      if (rawExists) Promise.reject(new Error('Data already exists'));
      const rawResult = await trx()
        .insert(item)
        .into<Departament>(this.tableName)
        .returning('*');
      await trx.commit();
      return rawExists ;
    } catch (error) {
      trx.rollback();
      return Promise.reject('Error adding departament Name: ' + error);
    }
  };
```

I don't know if with this logic it is good to insert a department to return all fields of the relationship something similar to what typeorm does

Comment: In an `async` function use `throw something`  instead of `return Promise.reject(something)`

Comment: I deal with errors in my useCase so I was using promise.reject

Comment: Don't. Use `throw`. That's one of the benefits of `async`. The two forms correspond but your approach is inconsistent and error prone. Actually, in your example, you don't use reject correctly, because you forgot to `return` and therefore your function never raises the error you think it does. Just use `throw`

Comment: OK I'll modify it, thanks, I forgot the return but I didn't have this notion of throwing the error already in the repository, could you help me with the knex?